# Create make with Qt4 and MySQL driver plugin

Tags: qt4, makefile, mingw, mingw32

Installing QT plain is no problem, but when you've got to recompile QT with a MySQL driver plugin?  Confusing.  And when I do run configure, Qt registers my MySQL driver, but when I attempt to run mingw32-make, this abomination shows up on my command prompt:

```
g++.exe: ....corelibcodecsqisciicodec.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files
mingw32-make[2]: *** [tmp/obj/release_shared/qisciicodec.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/2010.04/qt/src/tools/bootstrap'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release Error 2]
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/2010.04/qt/src/tools/bootstrap'
mingw32-make: *** [sub-tools-bootstrap-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Here are my specs:

- Windows 7 Nokia's Open Source QT
- Qt SDK for Windows (C:\Qt\2010.04\qt)
- Linux MinGW Version 5.1.6 (C\Linux\MinGW)
- MySQL5 with C++ files (C:\MySQL5)

And my environmental variables:

```
QMAKESPEC    win32-g++
QTDIR        C:\Qt\2010.04\qt
Path         C:\Linux\MinGW\bin;%C:\Linux\Cygwin\bin;C:\MySQL5\bin
```

These sites each have their own method of doing this.  I tried following them, but failed
http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_the_QMYSQL_plugin_on_Windows_using_mingw
http://jeethurao.com/blog/?p=18.

Assist me in allowing me to use the MySQL driver plugin.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The MySQL driver is licensed under the GPL license because libmysql is GPL, that's why you have to build it yourself. Unless you have a very very good reason, I advise you don't compile it it but leave it as a shared library - otherwise all your app code will become GPL.

Comment: Just noticed - that should have been "compile it in", not "compile it it".

Comment: Sorry that I have been long in replying; I had to leave the project for a short while.  I did take your advice, I am using it as a plugin, which should be the same as a shared library when it comes to licensing.  As for the project, I've gotten further now, and am having problems here @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494875/win7-mingw-qt-mysql-program-screams-cannot-find-lqsqlmysqld-where-is-the-miss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up installing the PyQT driver @ http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

This executable has MySQL support out of the box. If mysql does not work, your application is the problem.

["The issue is that you either have to use the addLibraryPath method or
create a QCoreApplication instance before your first call to loading a database"](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-06/thread00292-0.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've never compiled that particular thing myself, but since you say you've compiled before and are re-configuring and attempting to re-compile it, have you done a "make clean" ?

From the looks of it you might be missing a path or missing a file, but first thing clean it to ensure you don't just have old object files gumming up the works.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that.  I found a precompiled executable mentioned below that solved my problem for me.